# Counter shows unread messages, but I cannot find them

Tags: microsoft-outlook

[image]

The counter shows 4 unread emails, yet when I filter to only show unread, there is nothing. This has only happened this week, and I can't see any unread emails by manually scrolling through either. I have restarted Outlook, and it still shows. It also shows on Outlook Online.

I have tried right-clicking the folder and 'Mark all as read', but this does not affect anything.

Comment: do you have subfolders in inbox? maybe one of them contains them?

Comment: @MátéJuhász Not to my knowledge. As you can see on the left-hand pane the Inbox is expanded, and Sent Items is the only subfolder (?!).

Comment: @MátéJuhász I also tried emptying my Drafts folder, but that didn't affect the number either.

Comment: What version of outlook is this? I don't think the number indicates unread messages, but something else.

Comment: @Nzall Whatever the latest 365 version is for Mac. What else could it represent? I've tried filtering by flagged, needs follow-up but there's nothing in either of those.

Comment: have you seen http://superuser.com/questions/577858/how-to-fix-the-wrong-number-of-unread-emails-flag-in-outlook-2013? It appears like the unread messages might be on the server.